# is this a Haar integral?

Tags: group-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory

Consider the Linear, time-varying, non-homogeneous ODE:
$$
\dot{x} = A(t) x + F(t)
$$
where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $A(t)$ is an $n\times n$ matrix which is function of time, and $F\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)$.
It is known that its solution from an initial condition $x_0$ at $t_0$ is given by
\begin{equation}
x(t) = \Phi(t,t_0)x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t} \Phi(t,\tau)F(\tau) d \tau
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Where the fundamental matrix $\Phi(t_2,t_1)$ is a one-parameter group of transformation for any fix $t_2$ or $t_1$ (not both). Does the integral in (1) have something to do with the Haar integral? If this is True, what conclusion may I derive from that integral? What new perspective of analysis would give me that conclusion?

Comment: In what *group* are you thinking?

Comment: The group of linear operators $\Phi(t,t_0)$ generated by all pairs $t$, $t_0$.